# Alamofire parameter with array in class

Tags: swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

This is a recurrent problem for me - can I use SwiftyJSON to do this or how?

How can you get the following JSON via .POST with Alamofire :

```
{
    "class":"Class of 1969",
        "students": 
        [
            {
                "name":"A name",
                "age":25
            },
            {
                "name": "B name",
                "age": 25
            }
        ]
}
```

I have the following class:

```
import UIKit

import SwiftyJSON

class Student{
    var Name:String = ""
    var Age: Int = 0
}

class StudentsOf1969{
    var Teacher: String = ""
    var Students = [Student]()
   }
```

Alamofire

```
        Alamofire.request(.POST,
            strUrl,
            parameters: parameters, // How?????????
            encoding: .JSON,
            headers: headersWish).responseObject {...
```

I have tried something like this - adding a var `dictionary: [String: AnyObject]` to the class:

```
class Student{
    var Name:String = ""
    var Age: Int = 0
}

class StudentsOf1969{
    var Teacher: String = ""
    var Students = [Student]()

var dictionary: [String: AnyObject]{
    get {
        return [
            "teacher": self.Teacher,
            "students": self.Students,
            // or
            "students": [self.Students],
            ]
    }
}


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to giving `StudentsOf1969` a `dictionary` property, you should do the same with `Student`. And then when you call the `description` method of `StudentsOf1969`, it will call the `dictionary` property for each `Student` in the array (which can be done quite gracefully with Swift's `map` function).

For example:

```
struct Student {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    var dictionary: [String: AnyObject] {
        get {
            return ["name": name, "age": age]
        }
    }
}

struct ClassOfStudents {
    var className: String
    var students: [Student]

    var dictionary: [String: AnyObject] {
        get {
            return [
                "class": className,
                "students": students.map { $0.dictionary }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I renamed `StudentsOf1969` to `ClassOfStudents` to make it more clear that it's, more generally, used for any class of students, not those in 1969. Also, your JSON referenced class name, not teacher name, so I modified that accordingly.

Anyway, you can now get the `parameters` dictionary by calling `dictionary` method of `classOf1969`:

```
let classOf1969 = ClassOfStudents(className: "Class of 1969", students: [
    Student(name: "A name", age: 25),
    Student(name: "B name", age: 25)
])

let parameters = classOf1969.dictionary
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was so much missing the $0.dictionary in an earlier try. Right on!